# Does the default constructor represent zero for generic types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010

Assume there is a function and it works

```
template <typename T> 
Range<T> IRange(T lower, T upper){
  ....
}
```

So

```
IRange(0,5)
```

will produce a `Range` with values [0,1,2,3,4]. The exact behaviour of `Range` class is not important.

However now I want a helper function

```
template <typename T> 
Range<T>
Repeat(T t){
    return IRange(T(), t);
}
```

so that

```
Repeat(5)
```

will also produce a `Range` with values [0,1,2,3,4].

The question is:

> Is using `T()` to get the **zero** value generically an ok thing to do?

I think so but something nags at me that this might be wrong.

Mostly this class will be used with **integer** types but anything else that fits the concept should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

If `T` is `int`, then

```
int i = int();
```

value-initializes `i`, which for `int` means it is zero initialized so that it holds value 0. (Note that this syntax does not require the presence of a constructor for built-in types such as `int`.)

In general, `T()` is value initialization and the value depends on what `T` is as defined below:

> [The effects of value initialization are:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)
>
> 1) if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called; (until C++11)
>   1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized; (since C++11)
>   2) if T is a non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized; (until C++11)
>   2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor; (since C++11)
>   3) if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
>   4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the default constructor represent zero for generic types in C++

No, it obviously doesn’t in general, e.g. for `std::vector<char>()`.

However, you need to think in terms of constraints or, equivalently, concepts. For what conceptual `T` types do your functions `IRange` and `Repeat` make sense? From what you’ve written, it seems clear that the types need to be somehow conceptually numeric.

C++ doesn’t yet have formal definitions of such concepts (C++20 will gain some) but defining an ad-hoc concept for numeric types is *relatively* straightforward (thought here are important subtleties) by basing them on what `int` does.

For your purpose this leaves you exactly at P.W’s answer: For numeric types, `T()` is a good candidate for the [identity under addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) (aka. 0). Equivalently, you can use “uniform” initialisation<sup>1</sup>, `T{}`, and some people prefer this especially for generic code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately [*“uniform initialisation” isn’t*](https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/uniform-initialization-isnt-82533d3b9c11), but you can ignore this in your case.

Comment: As a side note, C++ has a named requirement [*NumericType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/NumericType), but this is different from the concept discussed here, though the intended use is somewhat similar.